# JsDoc links to properties of classes

Tags: class, properties, reference, jsdoc

I'm attempting to document a model used by my project using JsDoc 3.3.0 hosted under NodeJS on Windows.  Almost everything is working, except I don't seem to be able to @link to properties of classes.  My comment is as follows:

```
/**
 * Encapsulates all data concerning the speed, acceleration and braking characteristics
 * of a train or enemy.
 * @class speedModel
 * @property {Float} value The current real speed.
 * @property {Integer} target The speed we are attempting to reach.  Always greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to {@link speedModel#max}.
 * @property {Integer} max The maximum value possible of {@link speedModel#target}.
 * @property {Float} acceleration The rate per tick at which {@link speedModel#value} approaches {@link speedModel#target} if it is greater.
 * @property {Float} deceleration The rate per tick at which {@link speedModel#value} approaches {@link speedModel#target} if it is lesser.
 */
```

Strangely, I can @link to speedModel without a problem, and if I add static members, I can link to them using speedModel.nameOfMember.  I'm following the documentation here: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-link.html.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a doc of the property inside the object, like this:

```js
/**
 * Encapsulates all data concerning the speed, acceleration and braking characteristics
 * of a train or enemy.
 * @class
 * @property {Float} value The current real speed.
 * @property {Integer} target The speed we are attempting to reach.  Always greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to {@link speedModel#max}.
 * @property {Integer} max The maximum value possible of {@link speedModel#target}.
 * @property {Float} acceleration The rate per tick at which {@link speedModel#value} approaches {@link speedModel#target} if it is greater.
 * @property {Float} deceleration The rate per tick at which {@link speedModel#value} approaches {@link speedModel#target} if it is lesser.
 */
function SpeedModel() {
  /** @property {Float} - The current real speed. */
  this.value = '';
};

/**
 * Converts kilometers per hour to miles per hour (see: {@link SpeedModel#value})
 * @param {Float} speed The speed in miles per hour
 * @return {Float} The speed in kilometers per hour
 */ 
function kmhToMph(speed) {
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.  The problem is that it isn't a real class - it's a model which just happens to be, and when imported from a file, won't be an actual SpeedModel.  Perhaps class is the wrong thing to use and I should be using interface?

Comment: You can create a [namespace](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-namespace.html) instead if it makes more sense

Comment: I guess this would make the most sense in this context; even if the objects aren't static, the schema is.  Thank you for your help!